# If i have endless loop while(true) how can i use an outside flag to stop/continue the loop?

Tags: c#

what i need to do is to add a button or two with a flag that will stop/continue the loop.
How can i do it ?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {
        cpuView();
        gpuView();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to go read the example code on MSDN here: [BackgroundWorker Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Their example shows the propper way to cancel the worker.

---

You can also use `break` to exit a loop:

```
bool stop = false;

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(stop)
            break; // this will exit the while loop

        cpuView();
        gpuView();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: And now you have 2 problems ;p

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class that has a boolean for cancellation and paused status.
Pass an object from that class in your backgroundWorker.DoWork([instance of MyCustomObject here]) args

You can update the property from your original thread using button events.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MyCustomObject cancellationStatus = e.Argument as MyCustomObject
    while(!cancellationStatus.Cancelled)
    {
        if(!cancellationStatus.Paused)
        {
            cpuView();
            gpuView();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the ned i used the backgroundworker cancel pending option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first you make a method that do the task. Then declare an instance of class `Threading` as

```
Threading thrd=new Threading(signature of method defined)
```

then write an event handler in any button you want.

```
t.start()
t.abort()
t.resume()
```

are the methods to start stop or resume a thread